# Problems with Double Linked List in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am making a double linked list which stores "boxes" in a warehouse with 5 shelves. Each shelf cant hold a linked list which holds the "boxes" on that shelf. Im having a problem where when I try to move one of the boxes I'll add the box to a different shelf, but when I try to remove the box from the old shelf my program will just remove the box I just added to the new shelf. Below is my shelf class code which sets up the lists and my warehouse code where the moveOneBox method that I'm having trouble with exists.

```
    package assignment2;

public class Warehouse{

protected Shelf[] storage;
protected int nbShelves;
public Box toShip;
public UrgentBox toShipUrgently;
static String problem = "problem encountered while performing the operation";
static String noProblem = "operation was successfully carried out";

public Warehouse(int n, int[] heights, int[] lengths){
    this.nbShelves = n;
    this.storage = new Shelf[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        this.storage[i]= new Shelf(heights[i], lengths[i]);
    }
    this.toShip = null;
    this.toShipUrgently = null;
}

public String printShipping(){
    Box b = toShip;
    String result = "not urgent : ";
    while(b != null){
        result += b.id + ", ";
        b = b.next;
    }
    result += "\n" + "should be already gone : ";
    b = toShipUrgently;
    while(b != null){
        result += b.id + ", ";
        b = b.next;
    }
    result += "\n";
    return result;
}

public String print(){
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < nbShelves; i++){
        result += i + "-th shelf " + storage[i].print();
    }
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}

public void clear(){
    toShip = null;
    toShipUrgently = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < nbShelves ; i++){
        storage[i].clear();
    }
}

/**
 * initiate the merge sort algorithm
 */
public void sort(){
    mergeSort(0, nbShelves -1);
}

/**
 * performs the induction step of the merge sort algorithm
 * @param start
 * @param end
 */
protected void mergeSort(int start, int end) {
    int middle;

    if (start < end) {
        middle = (start + end) / 2;

        mergeSort(start, middle);
        mergeSort(middle + 1, end);

        merge(start, middle, end);
    }
}

/**
 * performs the merge part of the merge sort algorithm
 * @param start
 * @param mid
 * @param end
 */
protected void merge(int start, int mid, int end){
    int sizeOfLeft = mid - start + 1;
    int sizeOfRight = end - mid;

    Shelf left_Array[] = new Shelf[sizeOfLeft];
    Shelf right_Array[] = new Shelf[sizeOfRight];

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfLeft; i++) {
        left_Array[i] = storage[start + i];
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < sizeOfRight; j++) {
        right_Array[j] = storage[mid+1+j];
    }

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = start;

    while(i < sizeOfLeft && j < sizeOfRight) {
        if(left_Array[i].height <= right_Array[j].height) {
            storage[k] = left_Array[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            storage[k] = right_Array[j];
            j++;
        }
    k++;    
    }

    while(i < sizeOfLeft) {
        storage[k] = left_Array[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while(j < sizeOfRight) {
        storage[k] = right_Array[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

/**
 * Adds a box is the smallest possible shelf where there is room available.
 * Here we assume that there is at least one shelf (i.e. nbShelves >0)
 * @param b
 * @return problem or noProblem
 */
public String addBox (Box b){
    int i = 0, shelf_Space_Available = 0, lowest_Shelf = 1001, index_Lowest_Shelf = -1;
    while(i < nbShelves) {
        if(b.height <= storage[i].height && b.length <= storage[i].availableLength) {
            shelf_Space_Available = storage[i].height - b.height;
            if(shelf_Space_Available < lowest_Shelf) {
                lowest_Shelf = shelf_Space_Available;
                index_Lowest_Shelf = i;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    if(index_Lowest_Shelf >= 0) {
        System.out.println(b.id+" adding to shelf"+index_Lowest_Shelf);
        storage[index_Lowest_Shelf].addBox(b);
        System.out.println(index_Lowest_Shelf);
        print();
        return noProblem;
    }
    else {
        return problem;
    }
}

/**
 * Adds a box to its corresponding shipping list and updates all the fields
 * @param b
 * @return problem or noProblem
 */
public String addToShip (Box b){
    //System.out.println("Add to ship has box: "+b.id);
    if(b instanceof UrgentBox) {
        if(toShipUrgently == null) {
            toShipUrgently = (UrgentBox)b;
            return noProblem;
        }
        else {
            Box temp = toShipUrgently;
            while(temp != null) {
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            temp = b;
            temp.next = null;
            return noProblem;
        }
    }
    else if(b instanceof Box) {
        if(toShip == null) {
            toShip = b;
            return noProblem;
        }
        else {
            //System.out.println(b.id+" is an instance of box. Adding to box list");
            b.next = toShip;
            toShip.previous = b;
            toShip = b;
        }
    }
    //System.out.println(b.id+" did not work");
    return problem;
}

/**
 * Find a box with the identifier (if it exists)
 * Remove the box from its corresponding shelf
 * Add it to its corresponding shipping list
 * @param identifier
 * @return problem or noProblem
 */
public String shipBox (String identifier){
    Box grabber = null;
    int i = 0;
    while((grabber = storage[i].removeBox(identifier)) == null) {
        i++;
        if(i >= nbShelves) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(grabber != null) {
        addToShip(grabber);
        return noProblem;
    }
    return problem;
}

/**
 * if there is a better shelf for the box, moves the box to the optimal shelf.
 * If there are none, do not do anything
 * @param b
 * @param position
 */
public void moveOneBox (Box b, int position){
    /*Box check;
    System.out.println("Removing "+b.id+" from shelf #"+position);
    check = storage[position].removeBox(b.id);
    System.out.println(check.id);
    print();
    if(check.id.equals(b.id)){
        addBox(b);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Box not moved -- not found.");
    }*/
    String problemOrNoProblem = addBox(b);
    System.out.println("Removing "+b.id+" from shelf #"+position);
    if(problemOrNoProblem.contentEquals(noProblem)){
        Box check = storage[position].removeBox(b.id);
        System.out.println(check.id+" removed from shelf "+position);

    }
}

/**
 * reorganize the entire warehouse : start with smaller shelves and first box on each shelf.
 */
public void reorganize (){
    Box compare;
    print();
    for(int i = 0; i < nbShelves; i++) {
        compare = storage[i].firstBox;
        while(compare != null) {
            moveOneBox(compare, i);
            compare = compare.next;
        }
    }
}
```

}

and my shelf class code.

```
package assignment2;

public class Shelf {

protected int height;
protected int availableLength;
protected int totalLength;
protected Box firstBox;
protected Box lastBox;

public Shelf(int height, int totalLength){
    this.height = height;
    this.availableLength = totalLength;
    this.totalLength = totalLength;
    this.firstBox = null;
    this.lastBox = null;
}

protected void clear(){
    availableLength = totalLength;
    firstBox = null;
    lastBox = null;
}

public String print(){
    String result = "( " + height + " - " + availableLength + " ) : ";
    Box b = firstBox;
    while(b != null){
        result += b.id + ", ";
        b = b.next;
    }
    result += "\n";
    return result;
}

/**
 * Adds a box on the shelf. Here we assume that the box fits in height and length on the shelf.
 * @param b
 */
public void addBox(Box b){
    if(firstBox == null) {
        b.next = null;
        b.previous = null;
        firstBox = b;
        lastBox = b; 
    }
    else {
        lastBox.next = b;
        b.previous = lastBox;
        b.next = null;
        lastBox = b;
    }
    System.out.println(b.id+" added");
    availableLength = availableLength - lastBox.length;
}

/**
 * If the box with the identifier is on the shelf, remove the box from the shelf and return that box.
 * If not, do not do anything to the Shelf and return null.
 * @param identifier
 * @return
 */
public Box removeBox(String identifier){
    Box temp = firstBox;
    while(temp != null) {
        if(temp.id.equals(identifier)) {
            if(temp.next != null && temp.previous != null) {
                temp.previous.next = temp.next;
                temp.next.previous = temp.previous;
                temp.next = null;
                temp.previous = null;
                System.out.println("Running normal removal "+identifier);
            }
            else if(temp.next == null && temp.previous == null) {
                firstBox = null;
                lastBox = null;
                System.out.println("Running only 1 box "+identifier);
            }
            else if(temp.next == null && temp.previous != null) {
                lastBox = temp.previous;
                temp.previous = null;
                lastBox.next = null;
                System.out.println("Running last box "+identifier+" previous box is "+lastBox.id);
            }
            else if(temp.next != null && temp.previous == null) {
                firstBox = temp.next;
                temp.next = null;
                firstBox.previous = null;
                System.out.println("Running first box "+identifier);
            }
            availableLength = availableLength + temp.length;
            return temp;
        }
        //System.out.println("Next box");
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    System.out.println("No box "+identifier);
    return null;
}
```

}

I would appreciate any help/tips anyone could give me, thank you.

Comment: That's a lot of code and a very vague problem description. Please try to condense it to a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `moveOneBox` should be like this:

```
public void moveOneBox (Box b, int position){    
    Box check;
    System.out.println("Removing "+b.id+" from shelf #"+position);
    check = storage[position].removeBox(b.id);
    System.out.println(check.id);

    for(int i = 0; i< nbShelves ; i++) {
      if(storage[i].height >= b.height && storage[i].availableLength >= b.length) {
        storage[i].addBox(b);
        break;
      }
    }
}
```

Your `reorganize` should be like this:

```
public void reorganize (){   
    Box compare;
    print();
    for(int i = 0; i < nbShelves; i++) {
      compare = storage[i].firstBox;

      while(compare != null) {
        Box nextCompare = compare.next;
        moveOneBox(compare, i);
        compare = nextCompare;

       }
    }
}
```